# How to set window size of QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I created a `QTableView`. When I press the button and open this table, it appears as a small box. How can I adjust the size of my window?

```
QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setFont(fnt);
view ->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Comment: do you just open QTableView ?  view ->show() ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. no peoblem showing the QTableView. I, couldn't set window size of my table. Imade it with  `view->resize(800, 600);`